# NSValue getValue: method returns garbage value on iPhone 6 but correct value on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, nsvalue

I am storing an `NSInteger` inside `NSValue` and while retrieving the value back I am getting a garbage value. The interesting part is that I am getting this garbage value on iPhone 6 and the correct one on iPhone 5.

Here is a part of my code:

```
NSValue *unknown = nil;

[self getValueForUnknown:&unknown];

if (unknown) {
    NSInteger unknownInt;
    [unknown getValue:&unknownInt];

    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)unknownInt);    // prints the correct value on iPhone 5 but a garbage value on iPhone 6
}

...

- (void)getValueForUnknown:(NSValue **)unknownArg {
    int x = 0;
    *unknownArg = [NSValue value:&x withObjCType:@encode(int)];
}
```

Note: Both the devices are running `iOS 9.3.1`

Comment: What happens when you use `NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)unknownInt);`?

Comment: it prints the value 0 when run on iPhone 5 but a garbage value on iPhone 6.

Comment: Are you sure?  Are they both 64-bit?

Comment: just a quick google search shows iPhone 5 is 32 bit while iPhone 6 is 64..
but still `NSInteger` should have been able to hold `int`, 64 bit or not :-/

Comment: The issue is using `%lu` and `NSInteger` under both 32- and 64-bit platforms.  You always need to cast it to `unsigned long`.

Comment: tried it.. but i'm sorry to say this, it doesn't make any difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred to Apple Docs for the correct usage of NSValue and found this:

[image]

I was trying to get back the `int` value into an `NSInteger` variable and after declaring `unknownInt` as `int`, everything is working fine now.